# ROS Installation on Fedora 19

Tags: ros, rosdep, rospkg, fedora, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS Groovy on Fedora 19, following the instructions at wiki/groovy/Installation/Fedora. However, running the line

> $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y

results in the following error:

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
> to system dependencies:
> pcl: No definition of [libusb-1.0-dev] for OS version [schrödinger’s]

locate libusb- gives:

> /usr/lib/libusb-0.1.so.4
> /usr/lib/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
> /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
> /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
> /usr/lib64/libusb-0.1.so.4
> /usr/lib64/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
> /usr/lib64/libusb-1.0.so.0
> /usr/lib64/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0

The problem was how to get the letter 'ö' readable in the yaml file because rosdep resolve is giving this error: ERROR: No definition of [libusb-1.0-dev] for OS version [schrödinger’s]. I solved this by changing the OS name in /etc/system-release to schrodinger and then editing the yaml file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66853/ros-installation-on-fedora-19/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add rosdep rules for Fedora 19.  It's correctly detecting the OS correctly but the latest definition for libusb-1.0 is for spherical.  https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml

How to submit changes is documented here: http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-23**:
You say that this doesn't work for you.  What did you do to try it? What errors did you get?

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-23**:
see above. basically, how can I get the 'ö' readable in the yaml file?

**Comment by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) on 2014-05-10**:
For the record, this is fixed in the latest release of rospkg: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/pull/54